# How to find closed sets in a given topological subspace

Tags: general-topology

I don't understand how to find closed sets for a topological space or a topological subspace. I understand that if $ X - A $ is open in $\tau $ where $ (X,\tau) $ is a topological space, then $ A $ is closed.

But, whenever I go to apply this I get stuck. Example problem I'm working on now:

Let $ X = \mathbb{R} $ have the open half-line topology $ C= $ { $∅$ } ∪ { $(a,∞,)│a \in \mathbb{R} $ } $ ∪ $ { $ \mathbb{R} $ }. 
Give a description of the closed sets of $τ_A$ for $A=[-1,2)$. 
By definition we have that

$τ_A= $ { $U∩[-1,2) $ |  $U \in C $} =

{ $∅∩[-1,2)$} ∪ { $[-1,2)∩(a,∞) |a \in \mathbb{R} $} ∪ {$ \mathbb{R}∩[-1,2)$} =

{$∅$} ∪ {$[-1,2)∩(a,∞)|a \in \mathbb{R}$} ∪ {$[-1,2)$}

Considering the middle set(s), { $[-1,2)∩(a,∞) |a \in \mathbb{R} $} , ..... For $ a ≥ 2 $ we have that $ [-1,2) \cap (a,\infty) = \emptyset $ and for $ -1 \le a < 2 $ we have that $ [-1,2) \cap (a,\infty) = (a,2) $ and so $ T_A $ becomes:

$ T_A $ = { $∅$ } $∪$ {$(a,2) | -1 \le a < 2 $ } ∪ {A}

The closed sets are then $C$, and ????

Am I even on the right track?

Comment: The set of closed sets  of $ A$ is $\{ A$ \ $S : S\in T_A\}$... By def'n  a closed set is the complement of an open set.

Answer (score 1):

- Closed sets in the subspace topology are given by intersecting closed sets in the ambient space with your subset i.e you just have to determine what the closed sets in the open line topology look like. Calling these sets $U_{\alpha}$, you have that closed sets in the subspace topology of $[-1,2]$ are $U_{\alpha} \cap [-1,2]$.

$\textbf{Hint}$: If your topology tells you that the open sets are $\{\emptyset\}, \mathbb{R}$ and $(a, \infty)$ then what are the closed sets by the complement definition?

Comment: So the closed sets $U_A$ are $[-1,2], \emptyset, and [-1,a]$ if I undertood? This leaves the closed sets of the subspace topology to be $ \emptyset $ and $ [-1,2] $?

Comment: No. The closed subsets are the complements of the open sets i.e $[-1,2], \emptyset, (-\infty, a]$. Now just think of all the possible sets you can get by intersecting these with $[-1,2]$. My original solution missed some (sorry).

Answer (score 1):

If open sets are generated by $(a,\infty)$, then closed sets are generated by $(-\infty,a]$. Intersecting those with $[-1,2)$, we obtain, for $1<a<2$, sets of the forms $[1,a]$, in addition to $\emptyset$ and $A$ itself.

Comment: I don't understand the importance of the second line. "Intersecting sets like this, we obtain closed sets that look like $(a_0, a_1]$". What are these closed sets with respect to. Are these the closed sets of $ C $?

Comment: Looking at this again, I think I made a mistake; I've fixed it now. I was thinking of a different topology.